# Magento frontend login broken on https

Tags: php, magento, session, cookies, magento-1.9

I've got a problem where a Magento site works perfectly fine with https enabled only for the checkout page but if I set the main unsecure address to https so that the entire site is on https the login process breaks.

The customer can enter their details and then be redirected back to the homepage but without being logged in.

The admin area is unaffected by this and continues to function as normal

As a note, the site lives in a subdomain of the main company url trade.mydomain.co.uk

I've tried lots of different settings in the cookies section of the admin panel such as setting the cookie lifetime to zero, chaning the cookie domain etc as well as this 'fix' to the Customer/Model/Session.php

```
public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
{
    $this->setCustomer($customer);
    //$this->renewSession();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
    return $this;
}
```

The above fix lets the customer log in, but then as soon as any other page is loaded they are kicked out again.

As for cookie settings in the admin area i've tried changing the lifetime to 0, I've tried setting the cookie domain to .mydomain.co.uk, mydomain.co.uk, trade.mydomain.co.uk.
I've tried setting the cookie path to / and a more complex path like trade.mydomain

Getting really confused now, the site works absolutely perfectly on HTTP, the admin area works perfectly fine on HTTPS. The problems only start when I set the unsecure domain to https. Unfortunetly full site https is a requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Create the directory app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model and then copy Session.php file into it. The Session.php file is stored at this path app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model.

As soon as you move the file to the specified location, try to seek for this section:

```
public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
{
    $this->setCustomer($customer);
    $this->renewSession();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
    return $this;
}
```

Now, focus on `$this->renewSession( );` section and make it look like a comment using `//`. Resultant coding will look like this

public function `setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)`

```
{
    $this->setCustomer($customer);
    //$this->renewSession();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
    return $this;
}
```

Now, clean out all the login cookies. It will work for you as far as I hope.

Comment: If you had read the full post you'd see I've already tried that fix